# How to identify if a java method is generic using reflection?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

How do I check if `getQueue()` in the sample code is generic using reflection?. One way is to go through the argument types and return type and check if they are instance of `TypeVariable`. I'm looking for something simpler.

```
Class SomeClass {
 <V> Queue<V> getQueue();
}
```

Comment: Due to type erasure you can't. And remember there is a single class - unlike c++ templates -, so for what <> should your reflection work?

Comment: I'm trying to get the meta data of the class/method. I'm not looking at a particular usage of the class/method. I guess erasure only applies to the use of generics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to find a method's argument types or return type to identify if has type parameters, because the class `Method` has a method `getTypeParameters` returning an array of the type parameters.

Here is an example showing the use of this method. I have also shown the use of 2 other methods here, since the terminology is incredibly confusing.

```
public class SomeClass {

    <V, U> Queue<V> someMethod(String str, int a, List<U> list) {
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Method method = SomeClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("someMethod", String.class, int.class, List.class);

        TypeVariable<Method>[] typeParameters = method.getTypeParameters();
        System.out.println(typeParameters.length);                          // Prints "2"
        System.out.println(typeParameters[0].getName());                    // Prints "V"

        Class<?>[] parameterTypes = method.getParameterTypes();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parameterTypes));                // Prints [class java.lang.String, int, interface java.util.List]

        Type[] genericParameterTypes = method.getGenericParameterTypes();
        System.out.println(genericParameterTypes[2].getTypeName());         // Prints java.util.List<U>
    }
}
```